# DIsplaying matrix in image view in android

Tags: android

I am doing some image processing in android but I got an initial problem in the following code.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

private Bitmap bmp; 
private int[][] rgbValues,redv,redg,redb;
public int[] nn ; 
int values,val, c;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //load the image and use the bmp object to access it  
    bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.capture);  

    //define the array size  
    rgbValues = new int[bmp.getWidth()][bmp.getHeight()];  

    //Print in LogCat's console each of one the RGB and alpha values from the 4 corners of the image  
    //Top Left  

    Log.i("Pixel Value", "Top Left pixel: " + Integer.toHexString(bmp.getPixel(0, 0)));  
    //Top Right  
    Log.i("Pixel Value", "Top Right pixel: " + Integer.toHexString(bmp.getPixel(31, 0)));  
    //Bottom Left  
    Log.i("Pixel Value", "Bottom Left pixel: " + Integer.toHexString(bmp.getPixel(0, 31)));  
    //Bottom Right  
    Log.i("Pixel Value", "Bottom Right pixel: " + Integer.toHexString(bmp.getPixel(31, 31)));  

    //get the ARGB value from each pixel of the image and store it into the array

    for(int i=0; i < bmp.getWidth(); i++)  
    {  
        for(int j=0; j < bmp.getHeight(); j++)  
        {  
            //This is a great opportunity to filter the ARGB values  
            rgbValues[i][j] = bmp.getPixel(i, j);  
             values = rgbValues[i][j];
             int rvalue = Color.red(values);
             Log.i("Pixel Value", "Red pixel: " + rvalue);
             int gvalue = Color.green(values);
             Log.i("Pixel Value", "Green pixel: " + gvalue);
             int bvalue = Color.blue(values);
             Log.i("Pixel Value", "Blue pixel " + bvalue);

        }  
    } 
    ImageView miamageview ;

    miamageview = ( ImageView) findViewById (R.id.imageView1);
    miamageview.setImageMatrix(rgbValues);

}
```

I want to display the rgbValues matrix as an image in ImageView (or any other view) but I got that error :

```
"The method setImageMatrix(Matrix) in the type ImageView is not applicable for the arguments `(int[][])`".
```

How can i display rgbValues matrix as an image?

Comment: Why are you not set size of image in xml.

Comment: There is no error in XML file , the error is in "miamageview.setImageMatrix(rgbValues);"  it says The method setImageMatrix(Matrix) in the type ImageView is not applicable for the arguments (int[][])". and rgbValues variable in my case is int[][].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ImageView.setImageMatrix()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageMatrix(android.graphics.Matrix)) is for setting the translation, rotation and scaling matrix of an image. It's not for setting RGB values. To set RGB values, you should use [Bitmap.setPixels()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#setPixels(int[],%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int)) or [Bitmap.createBitmap()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#createBitmap(int[],%20int,%20int,%20android.graphics.Bitmap.Config)). Also, you need to put your RGB values into a 1-dimensional array, not a 2-dimensional one. Don't ask me why, it's the Android API (it's probably for speed reasons).

So, change your code to write to a 1D array:

```
private int[] rgbValues;
```

Use array[(y * width) + x] instead of array[y][x] or array[x][y] to address a 1D array as if it was a 2D array:

```
//define the array size  
rgbValues = new int[bmp.getWidth() * bmp.getHeight()];  

//Print in LogCat's console each of one the RGB and alpha values from the 4 corners of the image  
//Top Left  

Log.i("Pixel Value", "Top Left pixel: " + Integer.toHexString(bmp.getPixel(0, 0)));  
//Top Right  
Log.i("Pixel Value", "Top Right pixel: " + Integer.toHexString(bmp.getPixel(31, 0)));  
//Bottom Left  
Log.i("Pixel Value", "Bottom Left pixel: " + Integer.toHexString(bmp.getPixel(0, 31)));  
//Bottom Right  
Log.i("Pixel Value", "Bottom Right pixel: " + Integer.toHexString(bmp.getPixel(31, 31)));  

//get the ARGB value from each pixel of the image and store it into the array

for(int i=0; i < bmp.getWidth(); i++)  
{  
    for(int j=0; j < bmp.getHeight(); j++)  
    {  
        //This is a great opportunity to filter the ARGB values  
        rgbValues[(j * bmp.getWidth()) + i] = bmp.getPixel(i, j);  
         values = rgbValues[(j * bmp.getWidth()) + i];
         int rvalue = Color.red(values);
         Log.i("Pixel Value", "Red pixel: " + rvalue);
         int gvalue = Color.green(values);
         Log.i("Pixel Value", "Green pixel: " + gvalue);
         int bvalue = Color.blue(values);
         Log.i("Pixel Value", "Blue pixel " + bvalue);

    }  
}
```

then create a Bitmap from this array and set to your ImageView:

```
ImageView miamageview ;

miamageview = ( ImageView) findViewById (R.id.imageView1);

Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(rgbValues, bmp.getWidth(), bmp.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
miamageview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code to set image from resource..

```
public static Bitmap drawableToBitmap (Drawable drawable) {
if (drawable instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
    return ((BitmapDrawable)drawable).getBitmap();
}

int width = drawable.getIntrinsicWidth();
width = width > 0 ? width : 1;
int height = drawable.getIntrinsicHeight();
height = height > 0 ? height : 1;

Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap); 
drawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
drawable.draw(canvas);

return bitmap;
```

}